# I need help in finding the sum of the sequence $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{50}\frac{4^n -3}{4^{1-n}+3}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I was doing an olympiad question from TESSELLATE 2023 and here it goes:

"The following 100 numbers are written on the board:
$2-1, 2^2-1, 2^3-1, ...2^{100}-1. $
Alice chooses two numbers $a,b$ erases them, and writes the number   $\frac{ab-1}{a+b+2}$
​
on the board. She keeps doing this until a single number remains on the board. If the sum of all possible numbers she can end up with is $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p, q$ are coprime, then what is the value of $\log_{2}{(p+q)}$."

I think it's sufficient to find $\frac{p}{q}$. As it is not specified in what way the numbers are taken, I am ASSUMING(I have no proof of this whatsoever) that the order doesn't matter. So I wrote the question like this:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{50}\frac{(2^{2k-1}-1)(2^{2k}-1)-1}{2^{2k-1}+2^{2k}+2}$ where $a<b$ and $a=2^{2k}-1$ and $b=2^{2k}$
After doing some simplification inside, this is what I got:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{50}\frac{4^n -3}{4^{1-n}+3}$
I don't know if it is my weak knowledge about sequences or my bad procedure for solving, I can not go any further. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: I would not assume that the order doesn't matter.  The problem specifically asks you to sum over all the possible final numbers, which at least suggests that more than one is possible.

Comment: I suggest:  first look at the problem with a smaller collection.  Replace $100$ by $3, 4$, or whatever.  Something for which you can compute everything out explicity.

Comment: Note that that expression isn't the answer. You have 50 terms of that form, and will need to repeatedly apply the $(ab-1)/(a+b+2)$ step to.

Answer (score 1):

Hints/Observations towards a solution.

- The idea is to find an invariant involving $a, b$ and $ f(a, b) =\frac{ab-1}{a+b+2}$.
- Given the denominator and the starting terms, if our starting terms are $x_i = 2^i - 1$, it seems helpful to consider $y_i = x_i + 1$ and manipulate from there.
- With that in mind, given $y_i = x_i+1, y_j = x_j+1$, we have $f(y_i, y_j) = \frac{y_iy_j} { y_i + y_j} - 1$.
- Hence, $ \frac{ 1}{ f(y_i, y_j) +1 } = \frac{1}{y_i} + \frac{1}{y_j}$. This is the crucial observation.
- (Slight logical step involved) Hence, what is the final number?
- Explain further why this final number is invariant under how we chose to pair up the terms.

Comment: I’m impressed :)